# show result from sql as html selectable element

Tags: php, html, mysql, group-by

I have SQL command, which will get list of all categories that I used within my table. (writting categories into "categories" column)

**SQL:**

```
SELECT category FROM `events` GROUP BY category
```

In PHPMYADMIN the result is correct, so I know my SQL command is good (each of them is separate category):

**MEDICINE

SLEEP

SPORT**

I need to get these values and wrap each of them in OPTION html tag, so I can use them on page in SELECTION element. I have a strong feeling I need to use PHP to generate something like this. Can you please inspire me with code?

Here is my attempt to at least see the list via PHP, but I have failed

```
<html>
    <body>
        <table>
            <?php
                include_once('config.php');

                $query1 = mysqli_query($query, "SELECT category FROM `events` GROUP BY category");
                //nefunkcny

                echo $query1;
                ?>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is what I would like to get, the ability to select the category on page

[image]

I would appreciate any advice on this, thank you in advance. 
If further clarification needed, please ask.
Have a nice day.

Comment: can you please show us, what you have tried so far.

Comment: Hi, I added screenshot link to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use a `while` to fetch the results.

```
// Perform queries 
$query1 = mysqli_query($query, "SELECT category FROM `events` GROUP BY category");

if (mysqli_num_rows($query1) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    echo "<select>";
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query1)) {
        echo '<option value="' .$row['category'] . '">' . $row['category'] . "</option>";
    }
    echo "</select>";
}
```

Comment: Perfect, works like charm, I would like to give you upvote but it says I need to get some reputation here. @julekgwa thank you so much, this code helps me to learn a lot.

Comment: I also atempted to make just echo on screen a simple list but seems like misses the condition (if there is more rows, but failed)    'code'<html>
    <body>
        <table>
            <?php
            include_once('config.php');
            $sql= "SELECT category FROM events GROUP BY category";
            $result=mysqli_query($query, $sql);
            //nefunkcny

            if ($result){
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                    echo $row;
                }
            }
            ?>
        
        </table>
    </body>
</html>

Comment: How to put code in the comment? (show help section did not help me)

Comment: `echo` is used to echo non objects, `$row` is an object use `print_r($row)` and to make a list you need to loop over the object and access each item.